# What is a Javascript Key?

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-server

I'm following the [Parse Server Javascript Docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) but I can't seem to figure out what a `Javascript Key` is and what it is used for.

The doc says to use: `Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY");`

I am using: `Parse.initialize("APP_ID");` to initialize my Parse App.

but for some reason this causes my script to terminate now after working for a year. So now I'm guessing I need to pass a javascript key for it to work.

What is a Javascript Key? Why is it useful? And How do I get one?

[image: These are my Heroku config variables]

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#using-parse-sdks-with-parse-server

Comment: @JGFMK Thanks, and to fix my other problem. I reverted to parse version 2.0.0 because Parse.initialize() isn't working in Javascript for parse 2.2 for some reason.

Comment: I would assume you'd have to have a heroku account for all this stuff. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs